# Image drops to right before fade on Chrome using bg switcher jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using bg switcher jQuery in a project but I'm facing an issue on Chrome.

the code i'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".wrapper").bgswitcher({
        images: ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/3.jpg"], // Background images
        effect: "fade", // fade, blind, clip, slide, drop, hide
        interval: 5000, // Interval of switching
        loop: false, // Loop the switching
        shuffle: false, // Shuffle the order of an images
        duration: 800, // Effect duration
        easing: "swing", // Effect easing
        position: "center top"
    });
});
```

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Not without some HTML at a minimum, and ideally a demo. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: images are tagged on js!
the html for this slider is a simple div:
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div>